# Not able to create Zip file for AWS Lambda Fx in Gitlab through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a lambda function through terraform for files present in gitlab repo however I am getting error in CICD pipeline:

**"./lambda_function.zip: no such file or directory"**

The folder (src folder) containing the lambda function python file is different than the folder (terraform) containing the terraform file.

My Gitlab Project looks like

ProjectName

-src

- lambda_function.py

-terraform

- lambda.tf

And the terraform code in lambda.tf is:

```
data "archive_file" "lambda" {
type = "zip"
source_file = "../src/lambda_function.py"
output_path = "lambda_function.zip"
```

}

```
    resource "aws_lambda_function" "automation-lambda" 
{filename=data.archive_file.lambda.output_path
  description       = "Creating lambda"
  function_name     = "lambda_fx"
  role              = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"  
  handler           = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  memory_size       =  128
  timeout           =  300
  source_code_hash  = data.archive_file.lambda.output_base64sha256
  runtime = "python3.7"
}
```

Please suggest how the issue can be resolved.

Thanks

Comment: I'm also getting this error, locally this works without a problem but in a pipeline it's saying "Unable to load <path to zip>": open <path to zip>: no such file or directory

Comment: Solution:  `locals {
  source_files = ["../src/ingestion/ingestion.py"]
}

data "template_file" "t_file" {
  count    = length(local.source_files)
  template = file(element(local.source_files, count.index))
}

resource "local_file" "to_temp_dir" {
  count    = length(local.source_files)
  filename = "${path.module}/temp/${basename(element(local.source_files, count.index))}"
  content  = element(data.template_file.t_file.*.rendered, count.index)
}
`

Comment: `data "archive_file" "lambda_function_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/temp"
  output_path = "${path.module}/abc.zip"

  depends_on = [
    local_file.to_temp_dir,
  ]
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem in short:**

The problem comes down to this: `terraform plan` creates `data.archive_file` resources, that are later used by `terraform apply`. If you do these two terraform commands in separate gitlab pipeline stages. The zip files generated in the `plan` stage, won't be available to the `apply` stage. Unless you add the output directory as an artifact

**The longer version of the answer**

If you are using multiple stages of the gitlab pipeline, one to plan, then one to apply. This is your problem.

The "dist" zip files are created during the plan stage, so you need to add the $PWD/dist as an artifact to your pipeline. Then in your apply stage, tell the pipeline it needs the plan stage, making the artifacts available to the apply command.

So in our pipeline, I had something like this:

```
plan_lambda:
  stage: plan
  needs:
    - init_lambda
    - validate_lambda
  script:
    - terraform -chdir=${PROJECT} plan -out=planfile ${args[@]}
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${PROJECT}/planfile
      # This is important, data.archive_file's are generated during plan stage, not apply, so these artifacts need to be stored
      # https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/issues/39#issuecomment-1013680518
      - ${PWD}/dist
```

and then in the apply stage

```
apply_lambda:
  stage: apply
  when: manual
  needs:
    - init_lambda
    - plan_lambda
    - apply_execution_role
  variables:
    PROJECT: lambda
  script:
    - terraform -chdir=${PROJECT} apply -auto-approve planfile
```

and here, the generated dist zip files generated in the plan stage will be available to the apply stage and your problem should be fixed.

For extra information and the entire conversation that led me to this solution, here is the ticket in the terraform github repository:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/issues/39#issuecomment-1013680518

**What does "dist" or "dist zip" files mean?**

Here is some terraform code which runs yarn to install node_modules and then packages up the source code into a zip file so you can deploy on AWS Lambda

```
resource "null_resource" "run_yarn" {
  triggers  =  {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "yarn --cwd ${local.root_path}/app/src install"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "app_src" {
  depends_on    = [null_resource.run_yarn]
  type          = "zip"
  source_dir    = "${local.root_path}/app/src"
  output_path   = "${local.root_path}/dist/app.zip"
}
```

So "dist" files, are the distributed zip files generated and uploaded to AWS Lambda

Comment: please clarify what is meant by "dist". Also, can you post the terraform code for zip file creation.

Comment: And if we have different environments like dev, qa & prod then how to specify the env in 
`needs:
    - init_lambda
    - plan_lambda
    - apply_execution_role`

Comment: The question you asked was answered, if you have another question, ask it in a separate question

Comment: To answer the question about dev, qa, and prod. Have separate AWS accounts for each and use different AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID's depending on what environment you wanna deploy to. You could use branches to setup different keys. But it's probably answered in another question already asked

Comment: I had to use `"${path.cwd}/dist/app.zip"` in my terraform file

And for the `.gitlab-ci.yml` instead of PWD had to use ${TF_ROOT}